# Intuitive explanation of singular homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, intuition, morse-theory

Let $J$ be a $\mathcal{C}^1$-functional over a inner product space. The local behavior of $J$ near an isolated critical point $u$ is described by the sequence of critical groups
$$C_q(J, u):= H_q(J^c\cap U, J^c\cap U\setminus\{0\}), \qquad q\ge 0,$$
where $c=J(u)$ is a critical value, $U$ is a neighborhood of $u$ and $H_*$ denotes singular homology with $\mathbb{Z}_2$-coefficients.

My question concerns the "$H_*$ denotes singular homology with $\mathbb{Z}_2$-coefficients". How to explain in words what does it mean? I am not interested in technicalities, I just want to understand how it works and what it is. Please, use simplest concepts as possible.

I hope someone of you could help me to understand.

Thank you in advance!

${\bf EDIT:}$ Here $J^c=\{u\in E: J(u)\le c\}$, where $E$ denotes the inner product space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Singular homology groups are the most fundamental algebraic invariant of topological spaces. A traditional but terrible metaphor claims that the singular homology groups measure the presence of holes in a space, since for instance $H_n(S^n),$ where $S^n$ is the $n$-dimensional sphere, is $\mathbb Z,$ corresponding to an "$n$-dimensional hole" in the $n$-dimensional sphere. Here you are seeing singular homology with $\mathbb Z/2$ coefficients, which gives a vector space over the field with two elements measuring, perhaps, something about holes in your space without respect for orientation.

*ADDED:* The groups in your question are *relative* homology groups. If $A$ is a subspace of $B$ then $H_n(B,A)$ measures something about holes that would be in $B$ if $A$ were treated as a single point. In particular, the homology of an $n$-dimensional vector space relative to the complement of a point is the homology of an $n$-dimensional sphere discusses above--this is perhaps the simplest case of your situation, when $c$ is the global maximum of $J$ over $E.$

If this all seems aggressively vague, well, the definition and proof of basic properties of singular homology would usually take a month or so of a basic course in algebraic topology. You should learn this material. Singular homology (and other theories computing the same groups in the end) was a central motivation for the entire subject of algebraic topology, and it and its descendants and analogues are at the heart of every part of modern mathematics that has the slightest algebraic bent. Singular homology is thus something that every mathematician should learn.

Comment: I'm pretty sure singular homology is absolutely fundamental for e.g., algebraic variety over characteristic $p$ (with Zariski topology), since there isn't any interesting maps $\Delta^n\to X$. /sarcasm

Comment: @KevinArlin would you mind elaborating why the metaphor regarding the $n$-dim holes is so terrible? Not trying to disagree but genuinely curious.

Comment: @KevinArlin What part of it is "stupid"?  Is a Zariski topological spaces not topological spaces?  If you are prepared to assert "[s]ingular homology groups are the most fundamental algebraic invariant of topological spaces" without reservation then you should be prepared to defend it for very important class of topological spaces that form the basis of an entire discipline.  Granted you could try to develop an analogous theory using results such as Dodd-Thom as in Suslin's homology of schemes, but that is not singular homology.

Comment: @Zest There are two main reasons.  The first is that the "hole" is only there because of the embedding in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ so is extrinsic to (any topological space homeomorphic to) the $n$-sphere.  The second is with what it is actually counting.  Homology counts submanifolds (up to boundaries), which is a different sort of "hole" than what homotopy groups are counting (closer to our intuition of "holes" because you are actually filling in the "hole" that is the open $(n+1)$-ball).  Spheres are terrible in helping to visualise this, but genus $g\ge2$ surfaces would provide a better picture.

Comment: that's very nice, never thought about it in that way but i'm really glad i asked. Thanks a lot for the explanation @user10354138

Comment: @user10354138 The Zariski topology of a scheme is not a central example of “a topological space”. It is a very common metonymy to say “a space” when what means is “a homotopy type”, especially when talking invariants of spaces, since these are nearly always really invariants of the presented homotopy type. And as we both surely know, analogues of singular homology are inarguably central to modern algebraic geometry, so it is hard to see how complaining about the Zariski topology here could be anything at the level of serious discussion.

Comment: @KevinArlin Well I suppose we disagree on how we should think.  I subscribe to the school of not picturing $\mathbb{R}^n$-like spaces when seeing "let $X$ be a topological space" just as not to think of vector bundles for "let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheave on $X$" or $L^2$ in the case of Banach spaces because that reflex do more harm than good.

Comment: @user10354138 Very well. Next time you’re making a serious point, I’d suggest making it in a straightforward manner.

Comment: @KevinArlin thank you for your answer, it results quite understandable for me. I have one question. You introduced the notation $H_n(S^n)$ and its meaning is clear. But what about the notation $H_q(J^c\cap U, J^c\cap U\setminus\{0\})$? There are two "arguments", how to read this thing? What does it "count"?

Comment: @C.Bishop Ah, good question. I’ve added a paragraph addressing that. It’s not clear to me what $J^c$ means, to try to give an example closer to what you’re reading—is it the $c$-level set of $J$ in the inner product space?

Comment: @KevinArlin thank you. It is $J^c=\{u\in E: J(u)\le c\}$, where $E$ denotes the inner product space.

Comment: @KevinArlin could you please help me with this last thing?

Comment: @C.Bishop I added a paragraph about this.